# Root test for radius of convergence of $\sum \sin n z^n$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

While trying to determine the radius of convergence of $\sum_n z^n \sin n$ I saw [this answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/518416/).

So I tried to apply the root test. The proof I produced is as follows:

We have $$ 0 < \sin n < 1$$

hence

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sin n)^{1\over n} = 1$$

since $K^{1\over n}\to 1$ for all $K > 0$.

But I was wondering if one can really apply it like this when the constant can be arbitrarily close to $0$. The result is correct with this argument but that might well be coincidence.

> Is this argument mathematically correct?

Comment: The root test yields

$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=|z|\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|\sin(n)|}=|z|$$

Therefore, the series converges whenever $|z|<1$ and diverges whenever $|z|>1$.  This test is inconclusive for $|z|=1$.

Comment: @Dr.MV So all I have to do is replace the limit with lim sup and the argument becomes correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the argument isn't correct.

For example, the sequence $u_n=\frac{1}{2^n}$ is such that $0 <u_n<1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. However $u_n^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{2}$ doesn't converge to $1$